# How to create json array in json array codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, codeigniter

I have been searching for the solution on how to create JSON array in JSON object from Mysql query. Need help from any of you.

My source data in mysql:

```
Table: parent
--------------------------------------
| id | firstname | lastname | rating |
--------------------------------------
|  1 | John      | Doe      | 9.3    |
|  2 | Marry     | Jane     | 8.5    |
|  3 | Paijo     | Masni    | 9.8    |
--------------------------------------

Table: children
------------------------------
| id |  idparent  | name     |
------------------------------
|  1 |  1         | John A   |
|  2 |  1         | John B   |
|  3 |  1         | John C   |
|  4 |  2         | Jane A   |
|  5 |  2         | Jane B   |
|  6 |  3         | Bang Jo  |
|  7 |  3         | Kak Jo   |
------------------------------
```

My MySQL Query:

Select p.firstname, p.lastname, p.rating, c.name as children 
from parent p join children c on p.id = c.idparent

```
Output:
-------------------------------------------------
| id | firstname | lastname | rating | children |
-------------------------------------------------
|  1 | John      | Doe      | 9.3    | John A   |
|  1 | John      | Doe      | 9.3    | John B   |
|  1 | John      | Doe      | 9.3    | John C   |
|  2 | Marry     | Jane     | 8.5    | Jane A   |
|  2 | Marry     | Jane     | 8.5    | Jane B   |
|  3 | Paijo     | Masni    | 9.8    | Bang Jo  |
|  3 | Paijo     | Masni    | 9.8    | Kak Jo   |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my output of JSON format that I wanted:

```
var profile = [
    {
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "rating": 9.3,
        "children": [
            "John A",
            "John B",
            "John C"
        ],
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Marry",
        "lastname": "Jane",
        "rating": 8.5,
        "children": [
            "Jane A",
            "Jane B"
        ],
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Paijo",
        "lastname": "Masni",
        "rating": 9.8,
        "children": [
            "Bang Jo",
            "Kak Jo"
        ],
        "id": 3
    }
];
```

The one I got stuck from generating the JSON is on the children: [], I want to have an array with double-quote "" separated by comma ',' inside the [].

Thank you.

NB: 
Currenty I am using codeigniter for my coding. If you have faced this kind of problem on codeigniter before, I'm looking forward to getting the sharing from you.

Comment: What is the source of your data?

Comment: The source of my data comes from Mysql database. Currently, I use json_encode() in codeigniter to generate the JSON array, but it turns out very general format without array inside json array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$people = array();
$person = array();

$person['firstname'] = "John";
$person['lastname'] = "Doe";
$person['rating'] = 9.3;
$person['children'] = array('John A', 'John B', 'John C');
$person['id'] = 1;

$people[] = $person;
$person = array();

$person['firstname'] = "Marry";
$person['lastname'] = "Jane";
$person['rating'] = 8.5;
$person['children'] = array('JaneA', 'JaneB');
$person['id'] = 2;

$people[] = $person;

$profile = json_encode($people);

echo $profile;
```

Gives the following output:

```
[{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","rating":9.3,"children":["John A","John B","John C"],"id":1},
{"firstname":"Marry","lastname":"Jane","rating":8.5,"children":["JaneA","JaneB"],"id":2}]
```

Comment: Thanks, Man. I got the solution inspired by your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, all, for the valuable responses.
I just got the solution.

After searching for any solution by using any available function in mysql (which I have used are json_extract() and group_concat() ), yet it didn't give the best format like what I wanted.

Inspired by the answers above,
I have made my code like this in Codeigniter that works perfectly:

```
$parent   = array();
$children = array();
$profile  = array();

$parent_query = $this->db->query("select firstname, lastname, rating, id from parent")->result_array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($parent_query); $i++)
{
   $children_query = $this->db->query("select name from children where idparent = '$parent_query[$i]['id']'")->result_array();

   $parent[$i]['firstname'] = $parent_query[$i]['firstname'];
   $parent[$i]['lastname']  = $parent_query[$i]['lastname'];
   $parent[$i]['rating']    = $parent_query[$i]['rating'];

   for($j = 0; $j < count($children_query); $j++)
   {
      $children[] = $children_query[$j]['name'];
   }

   $parent[$i]['children']  = $children;
}

$profile = json_encode($parent);
```

The result given:

```
[  
   {  
      "firstname":"John",
      "lastname":"Doe",
      "rating":9.3,
      "children":[  
         "John A",
         "John B",
         "John C"
      ],
      "id":1
   },
   {  
      "firstname":"Marry",
      "lastname":"Jane",
      "rating":8.5,
      "children":[  
         "Jane A",
         "Jane B"
      ],
      "id":2
   },
   {  
      "firstname":"Paijo",
      "lastname":"Masni",
      "rating":9.8,
      "children":[  
         "Bang Jo",
         "Kak Jo"
      ],
      "id":3
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using NEIL's array structure,

In codeigniter, use the following code at the end for encoding.

`$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
$this->output->set_output(json_encode($your_array));`

It will output the following:

`"[{\"firstname\":\"John\",\"lastname\":\"Doe\",\"rating\":9.3,\"children\":[\"John A\",\"John B\",\"John C\"],\"id\":1},{\"firstname\":\"Marry\",\"lastname\":\"Jane\",\"rating\":8.5,\"children\":[\"JaneA\",\"JaneB\"],\"id\":2}]"`

And in AJAX return, use the $.parseJSON(data) to get your required result.